# Xcode 9 running Swift - Need help increasing Navigation Bar size and using images as Bar Button Items

Tags: swift, xcode, xcode9

I'm very new to Xcode and have run into an issue with the navigation bar.  I'm working on a 3 tab app and want to add a navigation bar at the top with a share icon and 4 social media icons.

I've created the navigation controller correctly.  I added 2 bar button items, uploaded the icons in the asset folder and selected the image in the Bar Item attributes.

I'm using Xcode 9, swift and need it to run on ios 10 & 11.

My first question is how to can I increase the length of the navigation bar so the icons will look larger on the screen?

Second is I'm having a problem with the images showing correctly on the nav bar with the green background.  The share icon on the left will show when I choose a white tint.  The icon on the right is supposed to be the Facebook icon but only shows a solid color.

[Screenshot of Navigation Bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TbowH.png)

How can I get the Facebook icon to be on top of the navigation bar background and show it's original colors?

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To increase the width of NavigationBar:**

Select your ViewController --> Navigation Item --> Prompt --> Add space it increase the height of **Navigation bar**[image]

**Programmatically provide the size:**

```
let leftView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 90, height: 21))
let leftButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 80, height: 10))
leftButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "facebook-icon-preview-1.png"), for: UIControlState())
leftButton.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
leftView.addSubview(leftButton)
leftView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
let leftBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: leftButton)
self.upperNavItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftBarButton
```